# virtualenv IPython in Spyder not working

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I have installed Spyder on Linux (Mint 17 to be exact) and created a scientific virtualenv (sci) with ipython, numpy, etc. The idea is to vary my virtual env for python 2 / python 3 and being a bit more flexible than installing the whole of Anaconda / python(x,y). I am having problems getting ipython to work in Spyder now.

I went to

```
Tools->Preferences->Console->Advanced settings
```

Use the following Python interpreter

```
 /home/mike/envs/sci/bin/ipython
```

but this did not start ipython. It responds with

```
...
Execute the given command[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Bad config     encountered during initialization:
[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '-u'
...
```

It also does not show "Open an IPython console" under Consoles.

any ideas what I am missing?

cheers, Mike

Comment: `Use the following Python interpreter` -> `/home/mike/envs/sci/bin/ipython`, well that's an `ipython` interpreter, not a `python` interpreter :)

Comment: that's what I figured, but how to get the ipython up and running? Mike

Comment: Have you tried just entering `/home/mike/envs/sci/bin/python`? I cannot promise, but probably spyder will take care of starting `ipython`.

Comment: @cel is right, you need to point to the python interpreter there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you correctly enter the path to the Python interpreter in your virtualenv (i.e. `/home/mike/envs/sci/bin/python`, not `/home/mike/envs/sci/bin/ipython`), you just need to go to the menu

`Consoles > Open an IPython console`

and, as long as you have IPython and PyQt/PySide installed in your virtualenv, an IPython console will be opened for you using the IPython version of your virtualenv.

Comment: `Tools->Preferences->Console->Advanced settings` no longer seems to have option to `Use the following Python interpreter` as of `spyder` v 3.1.3 under linux

Comment: @LaurenceBillingham, that option was moved to `Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter` in Spyder 3. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

the process is described in the following link :

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

It is recommended to install a modular approach with spyder-kernels:

1. activate the environment where you want to work (ex : `source env/bin/activate`)
2. install the kernel in the environment by typing : `pip install spyder-kernels==0.*`
3. get the interpreter path to be used by typing :  `python -c "import sys;
   print(sys.executable)"`
4. copy this path
5. enter the path in Spyder in the menu

> Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following interpreter

that should work, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Solutions above didn't work for me. What worked for me was following this guide in the docs:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel

1) open terminal and activate your virtualenv
2) still in the terminal, run the command: `python -m spyder_kernels.console`, you will get a message like:

```
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
--existing kernel-28340.json
```

3) to locate this json file location, run this in spyder:

```
from jupyter_core import paths
paths.jupyter_runtime_dir()
```

for me it was c:\Users[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\

4) In jupyter, from menu, click on "Consoles => Connect to an existing kernel"