# Installing tensorflow with anaconda in windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, tensorflow, conda

I have installed Anaconda on Windows 64 bit. I have downloaded PyCharm for creating a project and in the terminal of PyCharm I have installed `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` using the following commands:

```
conda install numpy
conda install scipy
conda install matplotlib
```

I am not able to install Tensorflow in the same way I installed these other packages. How should I install it?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-environment-installation

Comment: I had similar issues (on win10, anaconda 64bit, all up to date)  about 2 months ago and read the documentation :) w/o much success. I ended up installing docker/kitematic and downloading a complete install there. Things might have changed, though, maybe @Selcuk knows more.

Comment: I have read the documentation but it only created an environment but does not install it. If I am trying to import tensorflow in pyCharm it gives error since that module does not exist

Comment: To use the venv from PyCharm you need to select the conda interpreter as the interpreter for PyCharm - example - go to file > settings > project > interpreter, select Add local in the project interpreter field (the little gear wheel) and browse the interpreter or past the path - for example: conda_root/envs/tensorflow/bin/pythonX.X as you

Comment: Though as stated in the answer below tensorflow is not available for Windows yet.

Answer (score 19):

Google has recently launched a newer version of TensorFlow r0.12 which include support of Windows both CPU and GPU version can now be installed using Python >=3.5.2 (only 64-bit) version.

For CPU only version open **command prompt** and enter follow command

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Follow this [TensorFlow on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) for step-by-step instructions.

**UPDATE**

To install current latest version please run following command:

```
pip install tensorflow #CPU only
pip install tensorflow-gpu #For GPU support
```

**UPDATE 2020**

TensorFlow 2.0 now has a single package for both CPU and GPU version, simply run

```
pip install tensorflow
```

If you're using Anaconda you can install TensorFlow GPU version and all of its dependencies (CUDA, cuDNN) by running:

```
conda install -c tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: can you please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315205/installing-tensorflow-with-pip-python-3-5-anaconda-in-windows)

Answer (score 13):

To install TF on windows, follow the below-mentioned steps:

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Use `pip install tensorflow` in place of `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, in case if you want to install CPU only version of TF.

Note: This installation has been tested with **Anaconda Python 3.5 (64 bit)**. I have also tried the same installation steps with (a) Anaconda Python 3.6 (32 bit), (b) Anaconda Python 3.6 (64 bit), and (c) Anaconda Python 3.5 (32 bit), but all of them (i.e. (a), (b) and (c) ) failed.

Comment: It's better to install tensorflow using `conda` than `pip`, because conda will install the correct `cudatoolkit` and `cudnn` dependencies automatically.  The official instructions tell you to download and install all that stuff manually.

Answer (score 5):

Currently tensorflow has binaries only for Unix based OS i.e. Ubuntu Mac OS X - that's why no mention of Windows in [setup docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-environment-installation).

There are long discussions on Github:

- Open - [Windows Support and Documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17)
- Closed - [How to install TensorFlow on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42)
- Closed - [How to install/run/use TensorFlow on windows machines?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/377)

---

A **SO** answer - [tensorflow — is it or will it (sometime soon) be compatible with a windows workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616094/tensorflow-is-it-or-will-it-sometime-soon-be-compatible-with-a-windows-work)

---

Suggestion:

> **For now, on Windows, the easiest way to get started with TensorFlow
> would be to use Docker**:
> http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#docker-based_installation
>
> It should become easier to add Windows support when Bazel (the build
> system we are using) adds support for building on Windows, which is on
> the roadmap for Bazel 0.3. You can see the full Bazel roadmap here.

Or **simply use a Linux VM** (using VMPlayer), and the stated steps will setup it up for you.

---

**For PyCharm** - Once `conda` environment will be created, you'll need to set the new interpretor (in conda environment) as the `interpretor` to use in `PyCharm`:

Now to use the conda interpreter from PyCharm go to ***file*** > ***settings*** > ***project*** > ***interpreter***, select ***Add local*** in the project interpreter field (the little gear wheel) and browse the interpreter or past the path.

The default location - the  environment lives under `conda_root/envs/tensorflow`. The new python interpreter 'll be at **`conda_root/envs/tensorflow/bin/pythonX.X`** , such that  the `site-packages` will be in `conda_root/envs/tensorflow/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`.

Answer (score 5):

Google has announced support for tensorflow on Windows. Please follow instructions at https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/tensorflow-0-12-adds-support-for-windows.html. Please note CUDA8.0 is needed for GPU installation.

If you have installed the 64-bit version of Python 3.5 (either from Python.org or Anaconda), you can install TensorFlow with a single command:
C:> pip install tensorflow

For GPU support, if you have CUDA 8.0 installed, you can install the following package instead:
C:> pip install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install tensorflow on windows following the instructions on tensorflow.org, using the conda method of installation, as given here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation. 
There are small differences on how to activate an 'environment' on windows, you call 'activate' directly without the 'source'. So, for me after installing anaconda the steps where:

```
C:\Users\Dunschm>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
C:\Users\Dunschm>activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Dunschm>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: Hi, I have not tried python 2.7, but I have my doubts it would work because the installation explicitely required python 3.5 (see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). Maybe if you're able to compile tensorflow from sources for python 2.7 ?

Comment: I am trying this with python 2.7 and in new conda env. Not successful. "tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." is the message I am getting when tried the command "pip install --upgrade "/path/to_whl_file/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl""

Comment: after struggling for hours, finally this one worked for me. thank you very much. here catch is  conda-forge

Comment: however, not able to install keras, it says it need tensorflow 2.2 or higher

Comment: this link is dead now

Answer (score 2):

`activate tensorflow`

`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` worked for me.

None of the other steps mentioned online helped, I found it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#using_conda) when trying to install an older version.

Eventhough the steps mentioned in the link seems to be for MAC OS X/Linux it worked in windows 7

You can install spyder along with this
`conda install spyder`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Open Anaconda Navigator.

Change the dropdown of "Applications on" from "**root**" to "**tensorflow**"

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5iPG.png)

Launch Spyder

Run a little code to validate you're good to go:

```
import tensorflow as tf
node1 = tf.constant(3, tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4) # also tf.float32 implicitly
print(node1, node2)
```

or

```
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have python 3.5 with anaconda. First I tried everything given above but it did not work for me on windows 10 64bit. 
So I simply tried:-

1. Open the command prompt
2. Check for python version for which you want to install tensorflow, if you have multiple versions of python.
3. If you just have one version, then type in cmd:

   ```
   C:/>conda install tensorflow
   ```

   for multiple versions of python, type in cmd:

   ```
   C:/>conda install tensorflow python=version(e.g.python=3.5)
   ```

It works, just give it a try.
After installation open ipython console and import tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow
```

If tensorflow installed properly then you are ready to go.
Enjoy machine learning:-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried several commands none but mentioning the python version (... python=version) worked for me in Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

I found a more recent [blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/) in Anaconda which instructs how to install the TF easily.
I used:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
```

Or for the GPU version (Make sure that you have NVIDIA GPU)

```
conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu
```

This way you will have different environments for different TFs.

Answer (score 1):

The following command from inside your command window (and preferably, conda environment) will work provided you have an Nvidia graphics card.

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Update conda

> Run the anaconda prompt as administrator

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

2) Create an environment for python new version say, 3.6

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

3) Activate the new environment

```
conda activate py36
```

4) Upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

5) Install tensorflow

```
pip install https://testpypi.python.org/packages/db/d2/876b5eedda1f81d5b5734277a155fa0894d394a7f55efa9946a818ad1190/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

If it doesn't work

> If you have problem with wheel at the environment location, or pywrap_tensorflow problem,

```
 pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

The above steps

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

will work for Windows 10 as well but the Python version should be 3.5 or above. I have used it with Anaconda Python version 3.6 as the protocol buffer format it refers to available on 3.5 or above.
Thanks,
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for Installing Anaconda Python 3.6 version and Tensorflow on Window 10 64bit.And It was success!

1. Go to https://www.continuum.io/downloads to download Anaconda Python 3.6 version for Window 64bit.
2. Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

   C:> conda create -n tensorflow
3. Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

   C:> activate tensorflow (tensorflow)C:> # Your prompt should change
4. Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/enter code here download “tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl”. (For my case, the file will be located in “C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads” once after downloaded)
5. Install the Tensorflow by using the following command:

   (tensorflow)C:>pip install C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads\ tensorflow-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

This is what I got after the installing:
[image]

6. Validate installation by entering following command in your Python environment:

   import tensorflow as tf 
   hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!') 
   sess = tf.Session() 
   print(sess.run(hello))

If the output you got is 'Hello, TensorFlow!',that means you have successfully install your Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Anaconda for Python 3.5 - Can install from [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe) for 64 bit windows
- Then install TensorFlow from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

(I tried previously with Anaconda for Python 3.6 but failed even after creating Conda env for Python3.5)

Additionally if you want to run a Jupyter Notebook and use TensorFlow in it. Use following steps.

Change to TensorFlow env:

```
C: > activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) C: > pip install jupyter notebook
```

Once installed, you can launch Jupyter Notebook and test

```
(tensorflow) C: > jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

**Open anaconda prompt**

make sure your pip version is updated

and you have python 3.4 3.5 or 3.6

**Just run the command**

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

you can take help from  the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and  [video](https://youtu.be/N_O6ecbYGMM)

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

I use windows 10, Anaconda and python 2. A combination of mentioned solutions worked for me:

Once you installed tensorflow using:

C:\Users\Laleh>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 # use your python version

C:\Users\Laleh>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Laleh>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Then I realized tensorflow can not be imported in jupyter notebook, although it can work in commad windows. To solve this issue first I checked:

jupyter kernelspec list

I removeed the Jupyter kernelspec, useing:

jupyter kernelspec remove python2

Now, the jupyter kernelspec list is pointing to the correct kernel. Again, I activate tensorflow and installed notebook in its environment:

C:\Users\Laleh>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow)C:> conda install notebook

Also if you want to use other libraries such as matplotlib, they should be installed separately in tensorflow environment

(tensorflow)C:> conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib

Now everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation [link](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/) is helpful and worked for me. Installs all dependencies and produces a working Anaconda. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50203324/1061281) answer is also helpful if you want to use it with spyder

Answer (score 0):

If you have anaconda version 2.7 installed on your windows, then go to anaconda prompt, type these two commands:

1. Create a conda environment for tensorflow using `conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow`
2. activate the tensorflow using `conda activate tensorflow_env`

If it is activated, then the base will be replaced by `tensorflow_env` i.e. now it will show `(tensorflow_env) C:\Users>`

You can now use `import tensorflow as tf` for using tensorflow in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but always faced some issue or other. Below steps with specific version only worked for me.

1> Create virtual env

```
#conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
```

2> activate env
#activate tensorflow
#conda info --envs

3> Install tensorflow

```
#conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

this will install tensorflow 1.10.0

```
#python -m pip install --upgrade pip
#pip install setuptools==39.1.0
```

3> Install keras

```
#pip install keras==2.2.2
```

Testing

```
(tensorflow) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

"Conda" installs some of the special packages that might have compiled in C or other languages.
You can use "pip install tensorflow" and it will work.