# How to install Tensorflow on Windows 10 with anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I know that there exists a link for installing Tensorflow for python 3.5 on
[Windows Installation link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). There also a similar question on [StackOverflow link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) also, but it case when I use this command:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
```

But it said Wheel package needs to be updated. So I updated it using pip and ran the application once again. The output was

```
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

So how do I solve this problem ? Please help.
I've tried to install the cpu version of TensorFlow.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130489/installing-tensorflow-with-anaconda-in-windows

Comment: @RohanSadale I already tried all that it didn't work. It's not a duplicate. So pls help me with another solution

Comment: Could you rename the pip package to "tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" and try again? Looks like pip may like "amd64" more than "x86_64"

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` and `pip -V`?

Answer (score 3):

```
conda upgrade conda
conda upgrade --all
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5.
activate tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This will create an "environment" that will contain all of your packages you need (the example above is just tensorflow) and you will be able to import that library **while you are in that environment** anaconda is really just used to manage packages and segregate projects that require different packages

When your finished with your environment, to close out use:

```
deactivate
```

these commands are slightly different on OSX/Linux so be sure to look them up if you are on a different operating system


If you are using TF for some machine learning then you will probably want these packages in your environment as well:

```
conda install pandas matplotlib jupyter notebook scipy scikit-learn
```

Place that line between (activate tensorflow) and (conda install)

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The executable, [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows) for python 3.5 is not available on the official website. 
An alternative to downloading that version is to download the latest version of Anaconda(3.6 as of 9 May, 2017), open your cmd shell in windows and execute the following commands. Note that the activate command is not fully supported in Windows Powershell. Click [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1519) to see why.

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
```

The answer has been borrowed from Anaconda Public Google Group.