# Which python platform is suitable for tensorflow

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I downloaded the TensorFlow into Pycharm's environment, python 3.6, and I get the following error:"tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"

I wanting to know please which platforms support the TensorFlow?

Comment: The wheel you downloaded is meant for Python 3.5. Get a 3.6 wheel instead; [Gohlke provides one](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Python 3.5 for this: "TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows." (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

How did you try to install TensorFlow? Have you used Anaconda?
If so, try creating an environment which uses Python 3.5:

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
```

(Taken from [Installing tensorflow with anaconda in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130489/installing-tensorflow-with-anaconda-in-windows))