# How to solve TensorFlow DLL issue

Tags: tensorflow

I have some issues with TensorFlow installation. I tried several ways, like downgrading to 2.0 or inhibit the use of version 2, but nothing worked.
Please see below the messages I get during installation and the error I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Scripts>pip install tensorflow
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.3.3 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.33.4)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.9.2 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (50.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5"->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\program files\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0->tensorflow) (3.1.0)
```

Error:

```
>>> 
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\salvo\Desktop\trading system\RETE NEURALE 4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Thanks a lot for your help, please let me know if more info is required to find the solution.

Comment: Add information about the TensorFlow version(CPU or GPU) you are trying to install and system information.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues that occur during tensorflow installation find their reason in the environment. You might tried installing one tensorflow version onto another, or had packages installed before, which do not work well with your desired tensorflow version.

I had that issue many time and I solved it by installing anaconda and create a clean tensorflow environment, where I then install the desired tensorflow version. I created a [tutorial](https://michaeljanz-data.science/further-topics/setup-python-environment-with-anaconda-git-bash-for-deep-learning-2/) for this, which might be interesting for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I followed you guide with no errors. After I opened anaconda 3 and spider, but there Tensorflow result not installed. From spider I ran "pip install tensorflow". After installation I get again the same code about the missing DLL. Do I miss something? should I set in spider the nigthly enviroment I created with your guide? I've no idea how... please let me know... thanks

Comment: Hmm, I do not use spyder, however, this thread might help you further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041511/how-to-use-tensorflow-on-spyder