# Tensorflow: No module named tensorflow.python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, spyder

When importing keras into Spyder, I am receiving an error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

I followed the instruction on Tensorflow page to install it, however it is not working. When importing Tensorflow only, I do not have any error message.

Details about my versions:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you install it to a virtual environment?

Comment: I think so - I followed this https://www.tensorflow.org/install/#anaconda_installation

Comment: So make sure the python version in spyder is using the `python.exe` from within your virtual envirnment

Comment: Sorry, how to do so?

Comment: Use the answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment), and skip the conda create since you already created it

Comment: Lucy, is this still an issue?

Comment: Thank you, problem was solved! The only trouble was finally the change of the environment