# Unable to import Keras in Spyder

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I tried to import the Keras library in Spyder but it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-c74e2bd4ca71>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Then I created a virtual environment and installed Keras in that:

```
cd virtualenv/
virtualenv -p python3.5 py-keras
source py-keras/bin/activate
pip install -q -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install keras
```

If I'm editing in that virtual env with the terminal I can import Keras successfully, whereas in Spyder it still throws the same error.

Comment: I guess, you need to tell spyder to use the python from this venv. You can follow instructions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219081/5538805

Comment: i've already tried that and it didnt worked ..btw thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have anaconda (as Sypder is a part of it) . Why don't you do

```
conda install keras
```

on terminal.
It install and works without any problem on spyder.

Comment: CondaIOError: Missing write permissions in: /home/betelgeuse/anaconda3

Comment: and sudo does not recognise conda ...btw thanks for reply.. :)

Comment: Check this, may be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/917490/unable-to-update-anaconda-packages-on-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: With conda, it is easy to install keras. I have done it the same way and works fine for me

Comment: thanks :) reinstalling it with root permission works :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try starting Spyder from the virtualenv as well?
You can activate your virtualenv as you did:

```
source py-keras/bin/activate
```

Then start spyder with the appropriate command from the command line:

```
spyder
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have the keras installed by using either ways.
`conda install keras` from conda command prompt OR `pip install keras` from command prompt pointing to `python36_64\Scripts`. but, the only extra step you need to do to get that realized in Spyder console is close the Spyder console and launch it again through Anaconda Navigator. Use start > Anaconda Navigator -> Spyder. You should be able to import keras.