# Starting spyder installed in virtual env

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, spyder, conda

I'm using Linux Mint.
Using Anaconda, I've just created virtual env with python 3.5 that's called AI.
When I'm running

```
(AI) karol ~ $ conda list
```

I can see e.g.:

```
spyder                    3.2.4            py35h27cea69_0  
python                    3.5.4               h417fded_24
```

I can also run `python --version` to get `Python 3.5.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

But, when I want to run

```
(AI) karol ~ $ spyder
```

My system starts spyder version 3.2.3 with python 2.7.
When I'm running `spyder3` it starts spyder with python 3.5.2 instead 3.5.4. 
On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment%20this) tread it worked to just run spyder when environment was active: 
How can I start the version that I've installed on this environment? Why is it starting spyder that is not installed here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `which spyder`?

Comment: /home/karol/anaconda3/envs/AI/bin/spyder
it's a correct one

Comment: Hey, sorry. It seems like it suddenly started working. Thanks for respond!

Comment: Did you restart your terminal?

Comment: Yeah, but I feel like I've tried it before. The only difference I can think of right now was to add anaconda/bin to path and export it in ~/.bashrc, because it kept resetting when I was exporting it in terminal. I'm sorry, I'm quite new in Linux, and don't know if that matters or not.