# Cannot run Spyder3 from Windows command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I downloaded Python3, on a laptop where I already have Python2, in two folders `Python3` and `Python27` respectively.

I have Windows 10, 64 bit.

`Spyder.exe`and `Spyder3.exe` are in the `Scripts` subfolders of the installation.

I added `Python27\Scripts` and `Python3\Scripts` to the `Path`environment variable.

Opening a command prompt and typing

```
spyder
```

correcty starts Spyder2, while typing

```
spyder3
```

results in:

[image]

--

I have seen online that this error usually occurs for `Pip3`, so I tried to upgrade spyder3, but this did not solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: i use to run Spyder and it wuld use whichever version corresponding to the activated virtual environment.  Since you have 2 versions of python you should be running virtual environments.  Are you using the Anaconda distibution of python? or how did you install python?

Comment: I just installed python from here, https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/ ...

Comment: Well you still need virtual environments.  You can easily google virtual environment and get instructions on how to make virtual environments...

Comment: as a matter of fact, I want to know how to call spyder3 from the command prompt *because* I want to launch withint  a virtual environment, whcih I use to use tensorflow.

Comment: If you want to use virtual environments and Spyder, is there a good reason you don't just use the Anaconda distribution? It's the [recommended way of installing Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/README.md) anyway.

Comment: It looks like some dependence are missing, can you check if all the dependencies installed for Spyder3 in your Python3 env: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html

Comment: I have all the Requirements listed under "installation with pip"...

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160738/3283333) work for you ?

Comment: The problem isn't the virtual environment. Is running spyder from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spyder executable changed from "spyder.exe" to "spyder3.exe" in their latest releases

So, in \WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.0Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\Scripts\spyder.bat:

replace spyder.exe
per spyder3.exe
maybe do it also for spyder_reset.bat

Comment: So  already have `spyder3.exe` in my installation directory (under `...\Scripts`). And I did not use WinPython to install it, so it would not be under there... ?