# Cannot run PIP commands from windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install some packages from the command prompt on my windows OS. I tried the steps given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697736/cannot-run-spyder3-from-windows-command-prompt) but they don't seem to work *for me*. I can use the spyder IDE to install the package and get on with it but I want to know how to do it from Command line. I am getting this syntax error.
[image]

Comment: You don't have to use pip inside the python interpreter. If you installed it, `pip`command should be available in your cmd. If it's not, you have to add it in windows path, or you have to do `/full/path/to/pip install django`

Comment: `C:\Users\Dell>python -m pip install django`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: Thanks. It's asking me to upgrade pip. Can I do that from spyder ide or it can only be done from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `pip`? Check it with using `pip --version`
If not, please install and after that, it should work with using:

```
pip install django
```