# Why is my anaconda python2.7 env opening as python 3 in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to set up an arcpy friendly environment for use with ArcMap10.4. Our code uses Python2.7 and my current installation of Python is 3.

Here are the steps I've taken so far.

Followed [Arcpy installation with anaconda](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119503/getting-arcpy-to-work-with-anaconda).

Created an environment within conda, forcing to 32bit.

`(base) C:\Users>set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1`

`(base) C:\Users>conda create -n arcpy104 python=2.7.10 numpy=1.9.2 matplotlib=1.4.3 pyparsing xlrd xlwt pandas scipy ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole`

`(base) C:\Users>conda activate arcpy104`

`(arcpy104) C:\Users>spyder`

Opens as Python3.7

Comment: Which version of python opens if you activate and then run just `python`? Can it be a conflict with your `base` environment?

Comment: @MatsLindh running `python` in the `arcpy104` does activate 2.7.10. My most familiar IDE is spyder so that is why I want to try and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder doesn't support conda environments yet. There is an open issue about it:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4223

However, you can install another copy of Spyder *inside* your conda env:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30170469/11451509

Comment: Ahhh that must be it then. I have an older environment I set up for 2.7 and it worked. I must have forgotten that I did that step previously! I'll give that a whirl now.