# Conda environment is in an unsolvable loop of 'The environment is inconsistent', how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, package-managers

A dependency conflict in conda environment seems to cause the environment to be in a state of self-conflict and it is unable to find any useful fix.

I've tried things like `conda install anaconda` and `conda update --all` but seems nothing works, they all leads to the same error:

```
(cv-torch) ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-P51:~/git/gate_detection$ conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==5.2.0=py37_0
  - pypi/pypi::nbconvert==5.6.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-server==1.0.6=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab==1.1.4=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::notebook==6.0.1=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyter-client==5.3.3=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::ipykernel==5.1.2=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-desktop==0.1.0=pypi_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==5.2.0=py37_0
  - pypi/pypi::nbconvert==5.6.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-server==1.0.6=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab==1.1.4=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::notebook==6.0.1=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyter-client==5.3.3=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::ipykernel==5.1.2=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-desktop==0.1.0=pypi_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                                                                    failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:                                                                                                                                                                          



Package libprotobuf conflicts for:
tb-nightly -> protobuf[version='>=3.6.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']
protobuf -> libprotobuf[version='3.5.1.1|3.5.1|3.5.2.*|3.6.0.*|3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|3.5.2|>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']
grpcio -> protobuf[version='>=3.5.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='3.5.1.1|3.5.1|3.5.2.*|3.6.0.*|3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|3.5.2|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']
opencv -> libprotobuf[version='>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0']

(cv-torch) ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-P51:~/git/gate_detection$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==5.2.0=py37_0
  - pypi/pypi::ipykernel==5.1.2=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-server==1.0.6=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyter-client==5.3.3=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab==1.1.4=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::nbconvert==5.6.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-desktop==0.1.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::notebook==6.0.1=pypi_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==5.2.0=py37_0
  - pypi/pypi::ipykernel==5.1.2=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-server==1.0.6=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyter-client==5.3.3=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab==1.1.4=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::nbconvert==5.6.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-desktop==0.1.0=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::notebook==6.0.1=pypi_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  failed
Solving environment: /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:                                                                                                                                                                          
Finding shortest conflict path for libprotobuf[version='>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0']:  13%|████████████████████▍                                                                                                                                    | 2/15 [00:00<00:00, 16.01it/s]


Package libprotobuf conflicts for:
tb-nightly -> protobuf[version='>=3.6.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']
protobuf -> libprotobuf[version='3.5.1.1|3.5.1|3.5.2.*|3.6.0.*|3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|3.5.2|>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']
opencv -> libprotobuf[version='>=3.4.1,<3.5.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0']
grpcio -> protobuf[version='>=3.5.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='3.5.1.1|3.5.1|3.5.2.*|3.6.0.*|3.6.1.*|3.7.0.*|3.7.1.*|3.8.0.*|3.9.0.*|3.9.1.*|3.9.2.*|3.5.2|>=3.5.1,<3.6.0a0|>=3.5.2,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6.0,<3.6.1.0a0|>=3.6.1,<3.6.2.0a0|>=3.7.0,<3.7.1.0a0|>=3.7.1,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8.0,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9.0,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.1,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9.2,<3.10.0a0']

(cv-torch) ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-P51:~/git/gate_detection$
```

When I attempt to resolve it manually by removing all the packages that caused the conflict, it gave me an even longer error:

```
(cv-torch) ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-P51:~/git/gate_detection$ conda remove tb-nightly protobuf opencv grpcio
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - pypi/pypi::jupyter-client==5.3.3=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::ipykernel==5.1.2=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::nbconvert==5.6.0=pypi_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytest==5.2.0=py37_0
  - pypi/pypi::notebook==6.0.1=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-server==1.0.6=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab==1.1.4=pypi_0
  - pypi/pypi::jupyterlab-desktop==0.1.0=pypi_0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                                                                    failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package parso conflicts for:
jedi -> parso[version='0.1.0|>=0.1.0,<0.2|>=0.2.0|>=0.3.0|>=0.5.0']
Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
openssl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
numpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
scipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
markupsafe -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
pyzmq -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
mistune -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
pytorch -> libgcc-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.3.0']
torchvision -> libgcc-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.3.0']
shapely -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
matplotlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package libopenblas conflicts for:
scipy -> libopenblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.2,<0.3.3.0a0|>=0.3.3,<1.0a0']
numpy -> libopenblas[version='>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.2,<0.3.3.0a0|>=0.3.3,<1.0a0']
Package cycler conflicts for:
matplotlib -> cycler[version='>=0.10']
Package pexpect conflicts for:
ipython -> pexpect
Package jupyterlab_launcher conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_launcher[version='<0.2|>=0.10.0,<0.11.0|>=0.11.0,<0.12.0|>=0.11.2,<0.12.0|>=0.13.1,<0.14.0|>=0.2.3|>=0.3.0|>=0.4.0|>=0.5.4|>=0.5.4,<0.6.0|>=0.6.0,<0.7.0']
Package jinja2 conflicts for:
notebook -> jinja2
jupyterlab-server -> jinja2[version='>=2.10']
nbconvert -> jinja2[version='>=2.4']
jupyterlab -> jinja2[version='>=2.10']
Package setuptools conflicts for:
bleach -> setuptools
matplotlib -> setuptools
ipython -> setuptools[version='>=18.5']
pygments -> setuptools
jinja2 -> setuptools
markdown -> setuptools[version='>=36']
pytest -> setuptools[version='>=40.0']
pip -> setuptools
Package tornado conflicts for:
notebook -> tornado[version='>=4.1,<7|>=4|>=4,<6|>=5.0|>=5.0,<7']
matplotlib -> tornado
ipykernel -> tornado[version='>=4.0|>=4.2']
terminado -> tornado[version='>=4']
nbconvert -> tornado[version='>=4.0']
jupyterlab -> tornado[version='!=6.0.0,!=6.0.1,!=6.0.2']
jupyter-client -> tornado[version='>=4.1']
Package numpy conflicts for:
pytorch -> numpy[version='>=1.11|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.9|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
shapely -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|1.8.*|1.9.*|>=1.11|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.7|>=1.8|>=1.9|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
matplotlib -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*']
torchvision -> numpy[version='>1.11|>=1.11']
scipy -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|>=1.11|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
Package jupyterlab-server conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyterlab-server~=1.0.0
Package libgcc conflicts for:
pytorch -> libgcc
scipy -> libgcc
Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
scipy -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
pyzmq -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0']
numpy -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.3.0']
torchvision -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.3.0']
pytorch -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=5.4.0|>=7.3.0']
matplotlib -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package python-decorator conflicts for:
ipython -> python-decorator
Package python-dateutil conflicts for:
matplotlib -> python-dateutil
jupyter-client -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.1']
Package jupyter_client conflicts for:
ipykernel -> jupyter_client
nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
notebook -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1']
Package nbconvert conflicts for:
notebook -> nbconvert
Package atomicwrites conflicts for:
pytest -> atomicwrites[version='>=1.0']
Package nbsphinx conflicts for:
nbconvert -> nbsphinx[version='>=0.2.12']
Package mkl_random conflicts for:
numpy -> mkl_random[version='>=1.0.2,<2.0a0']
Package jupyterlab_server conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=0.2.0,<0.3.0|>=1.0.0,<2.0.0']
Package backports.functools_lru_cache conflicts for:
matplotlib -> backports.functools_lru_cache
Package entrypoints conflicts for:
nbconvert -> entrypoints[version='>=0.2.2']
Package webencodings conflicts for:
bleach -> webencodings
Package pandocfilters conflicts for:
nbconvert -> pandocfilters[version='>=1.4.1']
Package futures conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> futures
Package openblas conflicts for:
numpy -> openblas[version='0.2.*|0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.15|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0']
scipy -> openblas[version='0.2.18.*|0.2.18|0.2.18.*|0.2.19|0.2.19.*|0.2.20|0.2.20.*|>=0.2.20,<0.2.21.0a0|>=0.3.3,<0.3.4.0a0']
Package ptyprocess conflicts for:
terminado -> ptyprocess
pexpect -> ptyprocess[version='>=0.5']
Package libsodium conflicts for:
pyzmq -> libsodium[version='>=1.0.16,<1.0.17.0a0|>=1.0.17,<1.0.18.0a0']
Package ipaddress conflicts for:
notebook -> ipaddress
Package backports.shutil_get_terminal_size conflicts for:
ipython -> backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
Package jupyter-client conflicts for:
ipykernel -> jupyter-client
nbconvert -> jupyter-client[version='>=5.3.1']
notebook -> jupyter-client[version='>=5.3.1']
Package packaging conflicts for:
pytest -> packaging
Package json5 conflicts for:
jupyterlab-server -> json5
Package pickleshare conflicts for:
ipython -> pickleshare
Package libblas conflicts for:
numpy -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0']
scipy -> libblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0']
Package libgfortran conflicts for:
numpy -> libgfortran[version='>=3.0']
scipy -> libgfortran[version='>=3.0']
Package * conflicts for:
scipy -> *[track_features=blas_openblas]
numpy -> *[track_features=blas_openblas]
Package ipython-genutils conflicts for:
notebook -> ipython-genutils
Package prometheus-client conflicts for:
notebook -> prometheus-client
Package tk conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> tk[version='>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0']
matplotlib -> tk[version='8.5.*|8.6.*|8.6.*,>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|8.6.*,>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package traitlets conflicts for:
ipykernel -> traitlets[version='>=4.1|>=4.1.0']
nbconvert -> traitlets[version='>=4.2']
ipython -> traitlets[version='>=4.2']
jupyter-client -> traitlets
notebook -> traitlets[version='>=4.2.1|>=4.3']
Package pytorch conflicts for:
torchvision -> pytorch[version='1.1.*|1.2.0.*|>=0.3|>=0.4']
Package pyparsing conflicts for:
matplotlib -> pyparsing
Package prompt-toolkit conflicts for:
ipython -> prompt-toolkit[version='<2.1.0,>=2.0.0']
Package freetype conflicts for:
matplotlib -> freetype[version='2.6.*|>=2.8,<2.9.0a0|>=2.9.1,<3.0a0']
Package blas conflicts for:
numpy -> blas[version='*|*|1.0|1.1',build='openblas|openblas|openblas|mkl|mkl']
pytorch -> blas==1.0=mkl
scipy -> blas[version='*|*|1.0|1.1',build='openblas|openblas|openblas|mkl|mkl']
Package six conflicts for:
absl-py -> six
bleach -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
prompt-toolkit -> six[version='>=1.9.0']
pytest -> six[version='>=1.10.0']
torchvision -> six
Package sphinx conflicts for:
nbconvert -> sphinx[version='>=1.5.1']
ipython -> sphinx[version='>=1.3']
Package mock conflicts for:
jupytext -> mock
Package libcblas conflicts for:
scipy -> libcblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0']
numpy -> libcblas[version='>=3.8.0,<4.0a0']
Package future conflicts for:
pytorch -> future
torchvision -> future
Package terminado conflicts for:
notebook -> terminado[version='>=0.3.3|>=0.8.1']
Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> xz[version='>=5.2.3,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
Package markupsafe conflicts for:
jinja2 -> markupsafe[version='>=0.23']
Package funcsigs conflicts for:
pytest -> funcsigs[version='>=1.0']
Package mistune conflicts for:
nbconvert -> mistune[version='<2,>=0.8.1|>0.6|>=0.7.4|>=0.8.1']
Package zeromq conflicts for:
pyzmq -> zeromq[version='4.1.*|4.2.*|4.2.1|>=4.2.3,<4.3|>=4.2.5,<4.2.6.0a0|>=4.2.5,<4.3|>=4.2.5,<4.3.0a0|>=4.3.1,<4.4.0a0|>=4.3.2,<4.4.0a0']
Package icu conflicts for:
matplotlib -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0']
Package pyzmq conflicts for:
jupyter-client -> pyzmq[version='>=13']
notebook -> pyzmq[version='>=17']
Package pathlib2 conflicts for:
pytest -> pathlib2[version='>=2.2.0']
pickleshare -> pathlib2
ipython -> pathlib2
testpath -> pathlib2
Package jupyterlab conflicts for:
jupyterlab-desktop -> jupyterlab[version='>=0.35.0']
Package more-itertools conflicts for:
pytest -> more-itertools[version='>=4.0|>=4.0,>=4.0,<6.0']
Package py conflicts for:
pytest -> py[version='>=1.4.29|>=1.4.33|>=1.5.0']
Package mkl conflicts for:
numpy -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2020.0a0|>=2019.3,<2020.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
scipy -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2020.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
pytorch -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2020.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
Package defusedxml conflicts for:
nbconvert -> defusedxml
Package ipython_genutils conflicts for:
notebook -> ipython_genutils
Package bzip2 conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
Package _pytorch_select conflicts for:
torchvision -> _pytorch_select[version='0.1|0.2']
pytorch -> _pytorch_select[version='0.1|0.2']
Package jedi conflicts for:
ipython -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
Package nose conflicts for:
ipython -> nose[version='>=0.10.1']
Package cudatoolkit conflicts for:
pytorch -> cudatoolkit[version='10.0.*|7.5.*|8.0.*|9.0.*|9.2.*|>=10.0.130,<10.1.0a0|>=8.0,<8.1.0a0|>=9.0,<9.1.0a0|>=9.2,<9.3.0a0']
torchvision -> cudatoolkit[version='>=10.0.130,<10.1.0a0|>=9.0,<9.1.0a0|>=9.2,<9.3.0a0']
Package babel conflicts for:
jinja2 -> babel[version='>=0.8']
Package backcall conflicts for:
ipython -> backcall
Package nodejs conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> nodejs[version='<10']
Package ipykernel conflicts for:
notebook -> ipykernel
Package jupyter-core conflicts for:
jupyter-client -> jupyter-core
nbconvert -> jupyter-core
notebook -> jupyter-core[version='>=4.4.0']
Package functools32 conflicts for:
matplotlib -> functools32
Package ipywidgets conflicts for:
nbconvert -> ipywidgets[version='>=7']
Package libpng conflicts for:
matplotlib -> libpng[version='>=1.6.23,<1.7|>=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.36,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
Package pytest conflicts for:
parso -> pytest[version='>=3.0.7']
jedi -> pytest[version='<5.0.0,>=3.1.0']
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a']
Package subprocess32 conflicts for:
matplotlib -> subprocess32
jupyterlab -> subprocess32
Package pygments conflicts for:
ipython -> pygments
nbconvert -> pygments
Package pytz conflicts for:
matplotlib -> pytz
Package cffi conflicts for:
pytorch -> cffi
Package numpy-base conflicts for:
numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.17.2.*|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0',build='py37hdbf6ddf_7|py37h2b20989_7|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py35hdbf6ddf_7|py27hdbf6ddf_6|py27h2b20989_7|py27h2b20989_6|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py27h81de0dd_1|py27h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h74e8950_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h7cdd4dd_0|py35h7cdd4dd_0|py35h3dfced4_0|py27h7cdd4dd_0|py37hde5b4d6_5|py36hde5b4d6_5|py35h2f8d375_4|py27h2f8d375_5|py37hdbf6ddf_3|py37hdbf6ddf_2|py37hdbf6ddf_1|py37h2b20989_4|py37h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_4|py36hdbf6ddf_3|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_4|py36h2b20989_2|py36h2b20989_1|py36h2b20989_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py35h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_4|py27hdbf6ddf_2|py27hdbf6ddf_1|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_4|py27h2b20989_2|py27h2b20989_1|py27h2b20989_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_0|py35h2b20989_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py36h9be14a7_1|py35h0ea5e3f_1|py37hdbf6ddf_8|py37h81de0dd_10|py37h7cdd4dd_9|py37h74e8950_10|py37h2f8d375_11|py37h2f8d375_10|py37h2b20989_8|py37h2b20989_7|py36h81de0dd_10|py36h7cdd4dd_9|py36h74e8950_9|py36h74e8950_10|py36h2b20989_7|py35h81de0dd_9|py35h7cdd4dd_9|py35h74e8950_10|py35h3dfced4_9|py27hde5b4d6_12|py27hdbf6ddf_8|py27h81de0dd_9|py27h81de0dd_10|py27h7cdd4dd_9|py27h74e8950_9|py27h2f8d375_11|py27h2f8d375_10|py27h2b20989_7|py27h2b20989_8|py27h2f8d375_12|py27h3dfced4_9|py27h74e8950_10|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py27hde5b4d6_11|py35h2b20989_8|py35h2f8d375_10|py35h74e8950_9|py35h81de0dd_10|py35hdbf6ddf_8|py36h2b20989_8|py36h2f8d375_10|py36h2f8d375_11|py36h2f8d375_12|py36h3dfced4_9|py36h81de0dd_9|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py36hdbf6ddf_8|py36hde5b4d6_11|py36hde5b4d6_12|py37h2f8d375_12|py37h3dfced4_9|py37h74e8950_9|py37h81de0dd_9|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py37hde5b4d6_11|py37hde5b4d6_12|py27h0ea5e3f_1|py27h9be14a7_1|py35h9be14a7_1|py36h0ea5e3f_1|py27h2b20989_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py27h2b20989_3|py27hdbf6ddf_3|py35hdbf6ddf_4|py36h2b20989_3|py36hdbf6ddf_1|py36hdbf6ddf_2|py37h2b20989_1|py37h2b20989_2|py37hdbf6ddf_4|py27h2f8d375_4|py27h81de0dd_4|py27hde5b4d6_5|py35h81de0dd_4|py36h2f8d375_4|py36h2f8d375_5|py36h81de0dd_4|py37h2f8d375_4|py37h2f8d375_5|py37h81de0dd_4|py27h3dfced4_0|py36h3dfced4_0|py36h7cdd4dd_0|py37h3dfced4_0|py27h74e8950_0|py35h74e8950_0|py36h74e8950_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py36h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_1|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_1|py27h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py35h2b20989_7|py36h2b20989_6|py36hdbf6ddf_6|py37h2b20989_6|py37hdbf6ddf_6']
Package nbformat conflicts for:
nbconvert -> nbformat[version='>=4.4']
notebook -> nbformat
jupytext -> nbformat[version='>=4.0.0']
Package wheel conflicts for:
pip -> wheel
Package configparser conflicts for:
entrypoints -> configparser[version='>=3.5']
Package pyyaml conflicts for:
jupytext -> pyyaml
Package wrapt conflicts for:
deprecated -> wrapt[version='<2,>=1']
Package notebook conflicts for:
jupyterlab-server -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.2|>=4.3|>=4.3.1']
Package testpath conflicts for:
nbconvert -> testpath
Package jupyter_core conflicts for:
notebook -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0']
nbconvert -> jupyter_core
Package python-pathlib2 conflicts for:
pickleshare -> python-pathlib2
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
openssl -> ca-certificates
Package ipython conflicts for:
ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0|>=4.0.0|>=5.0|>=5.0.0']
Package matplotlib-base conflicts for:
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='2.1.2|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|3.0.1|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1',build='py37hfd891ef_0|py37he7580a8_1|py37hfd891ef_1|py37h5f35d83_0|py37h5f35d83_1|py37h167e16e_0|py36h5f35d83_1|py36h167e16e_0|py37h167e16e_1001|py37hc2fb212_1001|py37h250f245_1|py36h250f245_1|py37h60b886d_1|py36h250f245_1|py27h250f245_1|py37h250f245_1|py27h60b886d_1|py36h60b886d_1|py27h250f245_1|py27hfd891ef_0|py36hfd891ef_0|py37hfd891ef_0|py36h167e16e_1000|py36h167e16e_1001|py36h167e16e_1002|py37h167e16e_1002|py36h5f35d83_0|py36hfd891ef_1|py36he7580a8_1|py36hfd891ef_0']
Package numpydoc conflicts for:
jedi -> numpydoc
Package libgfortran-ng conflicts for:
numpy -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7,<8.0a0|>=7.2.0,<8.0a0']
scipy -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0|>=7.2.0,<8.0a0']
Package nccl conflicts for:
pytorch -> nccl[version='<2']
Package liblapack conflicts for:
...
```

In this case, how to make conda saving itself? Also, why conda's conflict resolver seems to be so much weaker than apt? The later always gave several alternatives that can results in a reliable fix.

Answer (score 2):

You have mix used `pip` and `conda`, which caused a dependency conflict. The simplest solution is to reinstall Anaconda to recreate the broken "base" environment.

**Tips**:

1. Use a virtual environment whenever you are working on a project. Don't install all packages in the "base" environment. The "base" is designed to work with `conda` the command, not recommended for your projects.
2. Don't mix use `pip` and `conda` in the same environment, unless you read the following reference.

#### Extended Reading

- [Create an environment from *Get started with `conda`*](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)
- [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)

Comment: That's not possible, some packages on pypi doesn't exist on any conda channel.
In the meantime, if there is a conflict the package manager should suggest uninstalling some of the violating packages. Which clearly 1. no suggestion was given 2. even uninstalling all packages in the error message doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda consists of a number of packages, so I normally start by:
$ conda create -n env_name python=3.6 anaconda

This way, it will pull in list of packages in anaconda from anaconda.org, and it should be self-consistent.

Many packages support conda install, but some only pip. The preference is to do conda install as it has a better dependency detection and resolution mechanism,

So after env is created, conda activate env_name, then conda install packages and then pip install the packages.

When I find packages are in conflict (say pkgA, pkgB, pkgC), I normally just do: conda install pkgA pkgB pkgC and let conda to pick and choose the one to resolve the issues. (This does not always though...)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

I created a new environment using this:

"What worked for me :

run spyder from the environment (after source activate)
go to

```
Tools --> preferences --> python Interpreter and select the python file from the env you want to link to spyder ex : /home/you/anaconda3/envs/your_env/bin/python
Worked on ubuntu 16, spyder3, python3.6."
```

[LINK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment/30170469#30170469]

Then proceed with installing the package I need. The issues were miraculously gone :)

Then I typed this in the anaconda environment

```
spyder activate MyEnvironment
```