# Error in Python 3.9.12 while using input command

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am using spyder in anaconda to run my python program (added the figure below to show my version ) [image].

When I type `input()` command in editor window[image], an error pops up [image].

(above)I have attached the screenshots of the same.

If I retain first part alone, there is no error.

Can someone help me as to why this error pops up.

I reinstalled the anan conda several times, thinking it was an installation error

Comment: Are you uisng `Virtual environment` ? If not so try creating one & launch spyder from there https://stackoverflow.com/a/47615445/15358800

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug in anaconda-spyder which a  lot of users have reported. I suggest one of the two appraoches :

1. Install ['non-anaconda'](https://www.python.org/downloads/) distribution of python and do `pip install spyder`.
2. Or check if your anaconda version is 5.1.5, if yes then check this - [link](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17623) or downgrade spyder or search other relevant links.